# Find limit of the quotient

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose $f,g$ are functions on $I=(0,2)$ such that $$\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = 1$$ and $$\lim_{x \to 1} g(x)= -\infty.$$ Prove that $$\lim_{x \to 1} f(x)/g(x) = 0.$$

for this question the main idea that i have going on is that ima have $|f(x)-1|< \epsilon$   and i have to somehow show that $|f(x)/g(x) - 0| < \epsilon$ but that's as far as i have gone.

Comment: This doesn't quite work -- note that in your case you have $-\infty$ instead of $N$. What is the definition of such a limit?

Comment: for the qoutient its actually |f(x)/g(x) - 0| < epsilon

Comment: that piece was wrong sorry wrong definition i want to prove fro g(x) that g(x) < -N

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon > 0$.
Then there is some $\delta > 0$ such that
$|f(x) - 1| < \epsilon$
for all $0 < |x-1| < \delta$ and there is some $\delta' > 0$
such that
$|g(x)| > 1/\epsilon$ for all $0 < |x-1| < \delta'$.
Thus for all $0 < |x-1| < \min \{\delta, \delta'\}$ we have
$$\bigg| \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \bigg| < \frac{1+\epsilon}{1/\epsilon} = \epsilon + \epsilon^{2}.$$

Comment: what were your side calculations to obtain delta 1 and delta 2 i seem to get stuck at |x-1| < delta1 thats for f(x) and similar for g(x)

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your question? Would you please reformulate it?

Comment: where did (1+epislon)/(1/epsilon) come from which then turned to epsilon + epsilon^2 but that is bigger than epsilon shouldnt we end with |f(x)/g(x)| < epsilon? so |f(x)/g(x)| < epsilon + epsilon^2 < epsilon?

Comment: In fact, the gist is that $|f(x)/g(x)|$ should be bounded by an $o(1)$ function, that is, by a function that $\to 0$ as $x \to 1$.

Comment: For example, suppose we are to prove that if $f(x) \to l$ and $g(x) \to m$ as $x \to 0$ then $f(x) + g(x) \to l+m$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then $|f(x) - l| < \epsilon$ and $|g(x) - m| < \epsilon$ locally. And we may end up with $|f(x) + g(x) - l - m| \leq |f(x) - l| + |g(x) - m| < 2\epsilon$ locally. Some authors would like to write this reversely, that is, write first that $|f(x) - l| < \epsilon/2$ and $|g(x) - m| < \epsilon/2$.

Comment: with this problem would it be possible to write it in the same manner? that form that you just wrote makes more sense to me than when there is an actual limit for some reason, for example why is |g(x)| > 1/epsilon?

Comment: Because $|g(x)| \to \infty$, which gives us a great degree of freedom to specify any desired bound. The point is that, for every desired lower bound $M$, there is some neighborhood around 1 on which $|g| > M$.